# How to move elements from a container to another one

Tags: ckeditor, comments, element, markers, ckeditor5

Hi everyone that my issu:

I have some text in my editor : `<p> Test </p>`. I put a comment on it (by using ckeditor comment feature) so it's in the model using markers.

Thanks to a button from a custom plugin, I'm trying to put my selection into a container to apply a class on it  : `<div class="selected"><p>Test</p></div>`

How can I do that without loosing the comment marker ?